# AngularJs + mansonry specific case

Tags: angularjs, masonry

I used angular with mansory, the default usage is :

```
<div masonry>
<div class="masonry-brick" ng-repeat="brick in bricks">
    <img ng-src="{{ brick.src }}" alt="A masonry brick">
</div>
```

cf : http://passy.github.io/angular-masonry/

But I want to use mansory with a specific case like this :

```
    <div masonry>
    <div class="masonry-brick" ng-repeat="brick in bricks">
        <div ng-if="date !== brick.publishedAt">
            {[{ brick.publishedAt }]}
        </div>
        <div>
            <img ng-src="{{ brick.src }}" alt="A masonry brick">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The specific case "ng-if" should be display an horizontal column with the publish date and after the associated articles display with mansory.
Actually, I cannot find the solution, and I don't knwon if it's possible.

Thank you for your help,

Best regards

Comment: You want to change _appearance_ of block depending on some _variable_ ?

Comment: Yes that's the idea, but the problem is, I think masonry is not planned to work when I want because the tag of the plugin is directly inserted into the div "ng:repeat". It doesn't work when I apply my condition in the specific block.


Best regards,

Comment: You can hack anything with `$templateCache`, `ng-if` and `ng-include`

Comment: I am newbie with angular and I don't see what do you mean and when I hack my problem with your solution.

Comment: Ng-if allows to define when your html block will be displayed and when it will not. You can create positive condition on default div you have and create separate after it with opposite condition. So each of that blocks will be displayed depending on conditions you wrote in ng-if

Comment: Yes, your solution is good but, I want to display informations in the same loop